# Printing out extra 0's while writing numbers in Expanded Form via javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Can't seem to figure out why I keep printing out extra 0's.

As of now, if the value was 730, this is what shows up:

```
Expected: '700 + 30', instead got: '700 + 30 + 0'
```

**Criteria:**

"You will be given a number and you will need to return it as a string in  Expanded Form. For example:

12 Should return 10 + 2

42 Should return 40 + 2

70304 Should return 70000 + 300 + 4

NOTE: All numbers will be whole numbers greater than 0."

---

```
function expandedForm(num) {
  var i,
      position,
      numArr = Array.from(num.toString()).map(Number),
      numArrLen = numArr.length,
      result = '';
  if(num < 10){
    return num;
  } else {
    for(i = 0; i < numArrLen; i++){
      position = numArrLen-1-i;

      if( i === numArrLen-1 ){
        result += numArr[i] * Math.pow(10, position);
        console.log('done',result);
      } else {
        if(numArr[i] !== 0){
          result += numArr[i] * Math.pow(10, position) + " + ";
          console.log('keep going',result);
        } else {
          continue;
          console.log('zero', result);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it goes into the first if check which does not account for zero so you need to check if it is zero in that check.

```
if (i === numArrLen-1 && numArr[i]!==0)
```

And the issue you will have after that is you will have a trailing `+`.

What I would do is instead of adding the string, I would push to an array and join

```
var result = []
result.push(30)
result.push(2)
console.log(result.join(" + ")
```

and you can use array methods to actually solve it.

```
(102030).toString().split("").map((n,i,a) => n*Math.pow(10, a.length-i-1)).filter(n => n>0).join(" + ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the solution.

```
function expandedForm(num) {
  // Convert num to a string array
  let numStringArray = Array.from(String(num));
  // Get length of string array
  let len = numStringArray.length;
  let result = '';

  // For each digit in array
  numStringArray.map( (n,index) => {
    // Perform only if n > 0
    if( n>0 ) {
      // Add plus sign if result is not empty (for the next digits)
      if( result ) { result += ' + '; };

      // Pad zeros the right limited to array length minus current index
      result += new String(n).padEnd(len-index,'0');
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This was my solution, could have been refactored better but it works.

function expandedForm(num) {

let myStr = num.toString().split(''), //convert number to string array
    strLength = myStr.length,
    arr = new Array();

if (strLength === 1) { /*If array length is one*/
    return num;
}

for (let i = 0; i < strLength; i++) { //loop

    if (myStr[i] === 0) { //if number starts with 0
        arr.push('0')
    }

    if (i + 1 === strLength) { //if array is close to end
        arr.push(myStr[i])
    }
    // add zero to number by length difference in array
    // add number to   
    if (myStr[i] !== 0 && i + 1 !== strLength) {
        for (let x = 1; x < (strLength - myStr.indexOf(myStr[i])); x++) {
            myStr[i] += '0'
        }  
        arr.push(myStr[i]);
    }
}
return arr.filter((obj) => obj.match(/[1-9]/)) //remove items with just 0s
    .map(obj => obj += ' + ') // add '+'
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b).slice(0, -2); //remove whitespace
```

}

Comment: Add some description to your answer

Comment: sorry I'll repost with comments

Answer (score 0):

```
function expandedForm(num) {
  const arr = num
   .toString()
   .split('');

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
   for (let j = i; j < arr.length - 1; ++j) {
     arr[i] += '0';
   }
  }
 }
  return arr
   .join()
   .replace(new RegExp(",0", "g"), "")
   .replace(new RegExp(",", "g"), " + ");
}
```

My solution is fairly similar, uses a bit of RegExp at the end in order to strip out the commas and lone zeroes however